# Display Formatted RTF in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, rtf, jtextpane

im trying to display in a JTextPane the text of a RTF file, it only show a plain text, but i need the formatted text with bold, font, sizes, etc...

here is the code:

```
public void mostraRTF() {
        RTFEditorKit rtf = new RTFEditorKit();  
        rtfDisplay.setEditorKit( rtf );  
        rtfDisplay.setBackground( Color.white ); 

        try {  
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream( "F:\\31012200.rtf" );  
            rtf.read( fi, rtfDisplay.getDocument(), 0 );  
            }  
            catch( FileNotFoundException e )  
            {  
            System.out.println( "File not found" );  
            }  
            catch( IOException e )  
            {  
            System.out.println( "I/O error" );  
            }  
            catch( BadLocationException e )  
            {  
            }  

    }
```

Comment: did you read official Oracle tutorial How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes

Comment: yes and i didnt found anything for RTF formatting! =/ @mKorbel

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12325248/230513).

Comment: @trashgod not working, just return this ``` <html>
  <head>
    <style>
      <!--
      -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class=default>
      
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [*Minimal, Complete, Valid Example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach.

Comment: if you see < html > tag I think invalid editorkit is used somehow (htmleditorkit rather than rtfeditorkit). You can check the kit http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html instead of default one.

Comment: @StanislavL it worked with advanced_rtf_editor for normal rtf, but the rtf that i need to use(another program generated it), it has a LOT of crazy informations in the begin and the advanced do not display, just show a blank screen :(