# How to open word document or excel document in the browser in java?

Tags: java

I am working on a web-based general purpose comparison tool which will maintain the history of any document like doc or excel.

But I am stuck on how to open word in the browser. I see aspose API but it is not free, is there any other solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us some code we can work with and describe more precisely which problems you encountered. Also, why would you want your caption to be bold?

Comment: Check this for word file [Viewing .doc file with java applet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12142928/387194)

Comment: And here is article how to read excel file http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-read-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). This library allows you to transform any document (word, excel, pdf) into HTML, which you can show in browser.